# Porting serial daemon + PHP to Windows

Tags: windows, serial-port, daemon

I have a Linux system with:

- a daemon that communicate with another device via RS232 port.
- a php + javascript web site that talks to the daemon through a
  socket.

Now the boss wants to find out how much of an effort is required to port all these onto Windowze.

Having never really programmed on Windows before, I'd like to ask how easy/hard this is going to be and what the options are.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

PHP will probably run as is.  Javascript runs in the web browser, and will run as is. Your daemon is a service on windows.  Apparently it listens on a socket for commands from the web page via javascript.

You did not state what language you are targeting for the service.  Some languages such as C# dot Net, have built-in libraries for making clean services that can pause, stop, start, and interact with the Windows Service Control system.  C# would be a good choice to make a service that can install and remove itself easily, and it supports nice high level socket control to listen to the PHP and javascript code.   I have used perl, C#, C++, and even Visual Basic running as a service, so the choice is yours.

If your choice of Windows language is that compiles to some .EXE, then a low-level way to add a service is as follows. You will need INSTSRV.exe and SRVANY.EXE, which come on the Windows Resource Kit, or can be downloaded easily with a quick web search.

## The short version :

After you get the server runnign when you are logged in and debugged, install the APP server as normal to the C:\Program Files\APP directory. This would be the app that connects to the serial port and does what you want via sockets.

Copy instsrv.exe to your C:\WINDOWS\system32 directory/

Copy SRVANY.EXE to C:\Program Files\YOURAPP

From command prompt, run this command – INSTSRV YOURAPP "C:\Program Files\YOURAPP\srvany.exe"

Run the Registry Editor (REGEDT.EXE)

Under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\YOURAPP: create a ‘Parameters‘ key (folder)

Under the this key, create a REG_SZ  string value called Application and add in this data C:\Program Files\YOURAPP\YOURAPP.exe

Close Regedit, then open the services console in administrative tools, or start, run, services.msc, confirm it is set to start automatically and the logon account is LocalSystem. Then unclick the Allow Service to Interact with Desktop.  If you click this, it will interrupt you on Windows 7 boxes whenever it writes to the screen.

Start the service, check in Task Manager, you will see YOURAPP.exe inthere, and if you stop the service then YOURAPP.exe will disappear.

## The long version

Details on this are at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890